# Android - Is this not possible to change the color of search icon in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, androiddesignsupport

I am using the default `ActionBar` in my android project. I am using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme.

I have created `XML` file for `menu` and the `search item` from this `menu` is below:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

When i load the application on physical device for testing the color of the `search icon` is not white, its a kind of reddish (the low color of the `ActionBar`), see the image below:

[image]

Title color is white which is OK, overflow menu button color is white which is OK, but the search icon button is not white. So, i did research and found the following sources in which no one is working.

1. [How to change searchview icon color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855532/how-to-change-searchview-icon-color?rq=1)
2. [How can i change the icon color of searchview in actionbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684202/how-can-i-change-the-icon-color-of-searchview-in-actionbar)
3. [how to change the icon color of search view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693116/how-to-change-the-icon-color-of-search-view)
4. [Change the text colors and icons of searchview in action bar.](https://mobikul.com/changing-color-icons-searchview-action-bar/)
5. [And all these .....](https://www.google.com/search?q=changing%20the%20color%20of%20the%20search%20icon%20in%20action%20bar%20site:stackoverflow.com&safe=active&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT2tWk78jjAhVIQMAKHdOpBckQrQIoBDABegQIBBAM&biw=1536&bih=754)

Eventually, i realize that there is no way to change the color of the default search icon in the `ActionBar`. I just want to make this question to be the last and long explanation of this issue which covers the `Why the icon color is different then the title color and overflow menu icon color?`, `Why this thing is impossible to solve?`, `Where this color property of xml for search icon is hidden that is hard to find?` and `How(if possible) to change the color of this default search icon in the ActionBar`? I know we can add the custom icon with white color here and we also have the `ToolBar`, but i don't want this solution because if its possible to change the title in `ActionBar`, add the overflow menu options into the `ActionBar` (etc) then it should also be possible to change the color of the search icon in the `ActionBar`. May be i found a hidden geek who knows this issue and can explain the `Why` and `What` to make this question the last informative/solution for future android folks.

If anyone want to negative mark my question, i am happily ready for this but at least this question will be helpful for the future android newbies. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the icon color is different then the title color and overflow menu icon color?

`@android:drawable/ic_menu_search`(You can find them in `Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\data\res\drawable`) is a png file with some transparent white color(That's why you get a white reddish color)

[image]

> Why this thing is impossible to solve?

It's not impossible, you can create your own icon as given below in this answer.

> Where this color property of xml for search icon is hidden that is hard to find?

There is no xml. Just png files. Depending on the theme android will choose one of them.(ie for Light Action bar a black icon and for Dark Action bar a white icon)

> How(if possible) to change the color of this default search icon in the ActionBar?

The solution is to create your own vector image for the search icon. You can assign any color you want. Then use this icon in the menu.

**Step 1: Create a Vector Image**

Right Click on `drawable` folder -> New -> Vector Assest

[image]

**Step 2: Create a Search Icon and choose a color**

Change the `Clipart` and `color`

[image]

**Step 3: Use this icon in the menu**

```xml
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: I know this. What is the issue with this color problem? Can you explain sir?

Comment: @Sunny updated with the information I could find, Hope this helps you

Comment: I am happy and glad for all these answers to my questions. And makes my concept clear.  Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Use below vector drawable

**ic_search.xml**  (res/drawable/ic_search.xml)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zM9.5,14C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: I know this. What is the issue with this color problem? Can you explain sir?